# Buffer Overflow: Why does buffer assignment impact other variables?

Tags: c, memory-management, buffer-overflow, stack-memory

```
void foo() {
    int value = 0;
    char buf[4];
    buf[4] = 1;


    printf("value: %d\n", value);
}

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Why does 'value' print 1?

I believe this has to do with buffer overflow and little endian but I am finding it hard to grasp.

Comment: It is *undefined behaviour*, since you exceeded the array bounds, but as it happened – and it need not be like this – the next byte was the little-endian least significant byte of another variable, whose other 3 bytes happen to already be 0. So `value` is `1`. When you write beyond the bounds of an array, it **always** damages *something*, which may or may not have an impact.

Comment: ...and there is no guarantee that variables appear in memory in the same (or reverse) sequence that you define them.

Comment: I understand it's undefined behavior. I was just wondering how this is related to little endian. When I went past buf[3] into buf[4], it started changing the next byte in memory. How do I know the next byte in memory is 'value'?

Comment: You don't, but obviously it was, and the next 3 bytes were 0. Try a different value and see if the damage corresponds. The behaviour is only *undefined* in the C Standard from a language perspective. The processor itself just does what it is told to. Iif bigendian, you might have see the *most* sig byte affected, i.e. `0x1000000` which is `16777216`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is Undefined Behaviour.

It is enough to change the optimization options and you will get different results.

Godbolt for example:

- With -O0 : 1
- With -Os : 0

But it does not have to be like this. It can end up in the segfault or something else may happen.

https://godbolt.org/z/TEbWbMvsa

> I understand it's undefined behavior. I was just wondering how this is
> related to little endian. When I went past buf[3] into buf[4], it
> started changing the next byte in memory. How do I know the next byte
> in memory is 'value'?

You cant know it. Order is not specified. `value` can be optimized out and not stored on the stack at all. You need to know your ABI and compiler very well to predict it.

In your case:

```
+ 0x07: value byte 4  MSB
+ 0x06: value byte 3
+ 0x05: value byte 2
+ 0x04: value byte 1  LSB
+ 0x03: buf[3]
+ 0x02: buf[2]
+ 0x01: buf[1]
+ 0x00: buf[0]
```